# Reordering Table Elements for an Email

Tags: html, css, email

I've been playing around and can't figure this out, so some advice would be greatly appreciated!

https://codepen.io/chaser87/pen/ZEQvydw

What I want to know deals with just the section headed by Meet your Department. When you shrink down this email, it stacks pretty much how I want it. However, I want to reorder the image and the block of copy in that section. Basically, I want the picture first, then the copy. I've tried doing nth-of-type stuff with  elements but isn't working.

For extra background, each section is a 100% table, with a 600 px table within, then another 100% table within.

```html
 <html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fjalla+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Boundless opportunities</title>
        <style type="text/css">/*<![CDATA[*//* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
            body, table, td, hr, a { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-textsize-adjust: 100%; }
            table, td { mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }
            img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }
    
    /* RESET STYLES */
            img { border: 0; height: auto; line-height: 100%; outline: none;
            text-decoration: none; }
            table { border-collapse: collapse !important; }
            body { height: 100% !important; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0
            !important; width: 100% !important; }
    
            
            @media screen and (max-width: 616px) {
                
                .fluid-table {
                        width: 100% !important;
                }
                table {
                        width: 100% !important;                 
                }
                td {
                    display: block !important;          
                }
                td img {
                        display: block !important;
                        width: 60% !important;
                        margin-left: auto !important;
                        margin-right: auto !important; 
                        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
                }
                
                h3 {
                    margin-top: 0 !important;
                    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
                }
                
                .paragraph-copy {
                    padding: 20px 15px 20px 15px !important;
                    font-size: 100% !important;
                    line-height: 25px !important;
                }
                .paragraph-align {
                    text-align: center !important;
                }
                    
                .social-icons {
                        padding: 5px 5px 10px 5px !important;
                        display: inline !important;
                        width: 15% !important;                  
                }
                    
            }/*]]>*/
            
            
            
        </style>
      </head>
      <body style="margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;">
        <!--END OF PREVIEW TEXT-->
         
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="fluid-table" role="presentation" width="600px">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td><img alt="It's your time. Apply in July! Join the Cowboy family as part of #okstate25 and you'll get a free T-shirt!" class="fluid-table" src="https://dummyimage.com/1200x696/000/fff" style="width: 600px;"/>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="paragraph-copy" style="padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px; font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif'; font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px; text-align: left;">
                            <p>{{First}},</p>
                            <p>We're excited to welcome you to the {{collegename}}! We look forward to seeing what the future holds for you as a {{major}} major within the Department of {{department}}.</p>
                          <p>We are here to assist you and look forward to working with you during your time at Generic State University. If we can help you in any way, please let us know. Again, congratulations on taking the next step and joining the {{college}}!&nbsp;</p></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!--FIRST ROW WITH PIC-->
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
    
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background-color: #E3E3E3" width="100%">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center">
                          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="600"><!--TWO COLUMN SECTION-->
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center"><!--TWO COLUMNS-->
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px"><!--LEFT COLUMN-->
                                      <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="36%">
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                              <tbody>
                                                <tr style="display: block; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between">
                                                  <td align="center" style="padding-top: 15px">
                                                    <!--CONTENT-->
                                                      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/220x220/000/fff" style="width: 220px;">
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                              </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                      <!--RIGHT COLUMN-->
    
                                      <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="56%">
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                              <tbody>
                                                <tr style="display: block; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between">
                                                  
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    <td class="paragraph-align paragraph-copy" align="left" style="font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif'; font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px; padding: 5px 10px 20px 10px"><!--CONTENT-->
                                                  <h3>
                                                    <span>Meet Your Academic Advisor</span>
                                                  </h3>
    
                                                  <p>{{Advisor_Name}}</p>
                                                  <p>{{Advisor_Address}}</p>
                                                  <p>{{Advisor_Phone_Number}}&nbsp; </p>
                                                  <p>{{Advisor_Email}}</p>
                                                  <p>{{Advisor_Bio Page}}</p></td>
                                                </tr>
                                              </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <!--END OF 2 COLUMN SECTION-->
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <!--SECOND ROW WITH PIC-->
    
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center">
                          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="600"><!--TWO COLUMN SECTION-->
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" style="vertical-align: top;"><!--TWO COLUMNS-->
                                <table align="" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px"><!--LEFT COLUMN-->
                                      <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="58%">
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                              <tbody>
                                                <tr style="display: block; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between">
                                                  <td class="paragraph-copy paragraph-align" align="left" style="font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif'; font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px"><!--CONTENT-->
                                                  <h3>
                                                    <span>Meet Your Department</span>
                                                  </h3>
                                                      <p>The {{Department}} is looking forward to your addition to the {{College}} family!&nbsp;</p>
                                                      <p>The main office for your department is located in {{department_address}} and you can reach them by phone at {{department_number}} or by emailing {{department_email}}.</p></td>
                                                </tr>
                                              </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                      <!--RIGHT COLUMN-->
    
                                      <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="36%">
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                              <tbody>
                                                <tr style="display: block; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between">
                                                  <!--CONTENT-->
                                                  <td align="center" style="padding: 15px 10px 10px 10px;"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" style="width: 200px"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                              </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <!--END OF 2 COLUMN SECTION-->
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                        
                        
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background-color: #E3E3E3" width="100%">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center">
                          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="600"><!--TWO COLUMN SECTION-->
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center"><!--TWO COLUMNS-->
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td style="padding: 5px 10px 0px 10px"><!--LEFT COLUMN-->
                                      <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="36%">
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                              <tbody>
                                                <tr style="display: block; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between">
                                                  <td align="center" style="padding: 20px 10px 0px 10px">
                                                    <!--CONTENT-->
                                                      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/210x210/000/fff" style="width: 210px">
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                              </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                      <!--RIGHT COLUMN-->
    
                                      <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="56%">
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                              <tbody>
                                                <tr style="display: block; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between">
                                                  
                                                    
                                                    
                                                    <td class="paragraph-copy" align="left" style="font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif'; font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px; padding: 5px 10px 0px 10px"><!--CONTENT-->
                                                  <h3>
                                                    <span>Mark Your Calendar</span>
                                                  </h3>
    
                                                  <p>Aug. 14 | Sample Event</p>
                                                  <p>Aug. 14 | Sample Event</p>
                                                  <p>Aug. 14 | Sample Event</p>
                                                  <p>Aug. 14 | Sample Event</p>
                                                  <p>Aug. 14 | Sample Event</p>
                                                  </td>
                                                </tr>
                                              </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <!--END OF 2 COLUMN SECTION-->
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                        
                    
    
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background-color: #E3E3E3" width="100%">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center">
                          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="600"><!--CONTENT-->
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td align="center" style="font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif'; font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px; padding: 15px 0px 5px 0px; vertical-align: top;"><hr style="border-top: 2px solid #000000; width: 50%;">
                                        <p style="padding-top: 15px;">Bookmark these calendars to stay informed about what's going on:</p>
                                        <p><a style="color: #FE5C00" href="#"><strong>Academic College Calendar</strong></a><strong> | <a style="color: #FE5C00" href="#">College Calendar</a> | <a style="color: #FE5C00" href="#">Athletics Calendar</a></strong></p></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <!--BOTTOM ROW LINK STORIES-->
    
                   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center">
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="fluid-table" role="presentation" width="600px">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td><img alt="It's your time. Apply in July! Join the Cowboy family as part of #okstate25 and you'll get a free T-shirt!" class="fluid-table" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x95/0fe5c1/fff" style="width: 600px; display: block;" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!--FIRST ROW WITH PIC-->
                      </tbody>
                    </table> 
                        
                        
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%" style="background-color: black">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center">
                          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="600"><!--TWO COLUMN SECTION-->
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center"><!--TWO COLUMNS-->
                                <table align="" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td><!--LEFT COLUMN-->
                                      <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="56%">
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td valign>
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                              <tbody>
                                                <tr style="display: block; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between">
                                                  <td align="left" style="padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px; font-family: Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'sans-serif'; font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px; color: #FFFFFF"><!--CONTENT-->
                                                  
                                                      <p>College of Engineering&nbsp;<br>
                                                        Generic State University<br>
                                                        136 Whatever Building | Orlando, FL 00000</p>
                                                      </td>
                                                </tr>
                                              </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                      <!--RIGHT COLUMN-->
    
                                      <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="38%">
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                              <tbody>
                                                <tr style="display: block; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between"><!--CONTENT-->
                                                  
                                      <td align="right" style="padding: 25px 15px 20px 0px;"><img alt="OSU's Facebook Page" class="social-icons" src="https://dummyimage.com/45x45/ddad45/fff" style="width: 45px;" />&nbsp; <img alt="OSU's Twitter Page" class="social-icons" src="https://dummyimage.com/45x45/ddad45/fff" style="width: 45px;" />&nbsp; <img alt="OSU's Instagram Page" class="social-icons" src="https://dummyimage.com/45x45/ddad45/fff" style="width: 45px;" />&nbsp; <img alt="OSU's Snapchat Page" class="social-icons" src="https://dummyimage.com/45x45/ddad45/fff" style="width: 45px;" /></td>
                                                
                                              </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <!--END OF 2 COLUMN SECTION-->
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
    
                   
                                    
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              </td>
    
    
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
                  
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `reverse` class to the cell containing Meet Your Department section's two columns and use the following CSS in your media query:

```
td:not(.reverse) {
    display: block !important;
}

td.reverse {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't work for me. I'm not seeing any changes. Perhaps I'm putting the class in the wrong cell? EDIT: Nevermind, I was right. I was putting it in the wrong place. Thank you so much for the help!